# PHP bind_result does not insert values into a array

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got an issue that the bind_result is not working (i think). I want the value of gamecode, admin, player2, etc. but it does not insert data into the array daten2. I've  spent a lot of time searching for the problem but couldn't figured it out.

i've used the same code just with different variables and it worked fine.

It is possible that player2, player3, etc can be **EMPTY**. Just in case this could be an issue.

The SQL Code works fine, i've tested it in phpMyAdmin

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "name"); 
$mysql->set_charset("utf8");


$spalte = $_SESSION["GamecodeSession"];

$stmt = $mysql->prepare( "SELECT gamecode, admin, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9 FROM room WHERE gamecode='$spalte'");
$stmt->bind_result($daten2[0], $daten2[1], $daten2[2], $daten2[3], $daten2[4], $daten2[5],$daten2[6],$daten2[7],$daten2[8],$daten2[9]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$_SESSION["NicknameAdminSession"] = $daten2[1];
echo "Admin:" . $_SESSION["NicknameAdminSession"] ; //The Session Variable is empty like every other
```

PS: I apologize for my english spelling misstakes, i'm not a native english speaker. "daten" is german and means data.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I've replaced the arrays with variables (ex: $daten2[0] is now $gamecode), Still does not work. Later in the code, i use another sql statement (Update) just in case this could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1. You need `session_start()` before using sessions
2. You are using prepared statements incorrectly
3. You are using bind_result at wrong location in code

**Code:**

```
<?php
session_start(); //Added

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "name"); 
$mysql->set_charset("utf8");


//This takes for granted GamecodeSession is always set    
$spalte = $_SESSION["GamecodeSession"]; 

//Do this instead

$spalte = '';
if (isset($_SESSION["GamecodeSession"])) {
    $spalte = $_SESSION["GamecodeSession"]; 
}

//You should never use value of an variable in the prepared statement:
$stmt = $mysql->prepare( "SELECT gamecode, admin, player2, 
player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9 FROM room WHERE 
gamecode='$spalte'");

//Instead do this (placeholder :spalte)
$stmt = $mysql->prepare( "SELECT gamecode, admin, player2, 
player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9 FROM room WHERE 
gamecode=?");

//Execute FIRST, then bind_result
//But before executing make sure $spalte value is included
$stmt->bind_param('s', $spalte); //s = string
$stmt->execute();

//Now bind columns to variables (after execution of the actual query)
$stmt->bind_result($daten2[0], $daten2[1], $daten2[2], 
$daten2[3], $daten2[4], $daten2[5],$daten2[6],$daten2[7],
$daten2[8],$daten2[9]);

$stmt->close();

$_SESSION["NicknameAdminSession"] = $daten2[1];
echo "Admin:" . $_SESSION["NicknameAdminSession"] ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the really detailed explanation to improve my php knowledge. I tried to understand your code and copyed it over to mine, but it still won't work. Let me know if you need more code from me.

Comment: What did not work? what errors you get?

Comment: I dont get errors, the variables are just empty. When i echo them, there is no Output. Example: echo "Player2: " . $player2; Output: Player2:

Comment: You bind the columns to variables you set yourself: In this you would like to show player you would have to echo "Player2: " . $daten2[2]'; because you set $daten2[2] in your bind_result and it is the third column. ($daten2[0]  would be gamecode, $daten2[1] would be admin etc). Just for debugging you could do var_dump($daten2);

Comment: I found the misstake and yeah it deserved every downvote... The variable "$spalte" is a integer and not a string. Thats totally my fault and not yours. But your answer really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Downvote should not be based on mistakes :-)